# SQL Server : script or stored procedure to find gaps in a counter column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have a SQL Server table `amPOrder` with a column `PONumber VARCHAR(30)` which holds purchase order numbers in the form `COM######` (i.e. the prefix `COM` followed by a leading zero padded integer of 8 characters length. The PO numbers are sequential but not necessarily unique (there can be an active PO and drafts sharing the same `PONumber`).

```
PONumber
---
COM142069
COM142082
COM142082
COM142083
COM142088
COM142090
COM142090
COM142090
COM142110
COM142111
COM142113
COM142113
COM142115
COM142116
COM142307
[...]
COM820111
COM820112
COM820113
COM820114
COM820116
COM820121
COM820122
```

Because of a recently uncovered bug in the software, the `PONumber` were wrongfully created with the following impact:

- many gaps between `PONumber` cause about 95% possible value to be "wasted"
- we are getting close to the maximum allowed `COM999999` maximum possible value

We want to identify the "free" `PONumber` values, i.e. int values from 100000 to 900000 for which there is no matching `PONumber` value in amPOrder and insert those within a new table (from which we'll be able to "consume" the gaps).

```sql
CREATE TABLE fix_amPOrder_PONumber 
(
    lValue INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    luserspid INT
)
```

Can one help with a "loop" between two integers which insert the current value if there is no matching `PONumber`?

### SOLVED

Working from @john-joseph answer, we did the following:

1. Create a `fillGap` stored procedure which takes the sttarting value and the number of rows to insert:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE fillGap
    @lValue INT,
    @times INT
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE @times > 0 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO fix_amPOrder_PONumber
            (lValue)
        VALUES
            (@lValue)
        SET @lValue = @lValue + 1
        SET @times = @times - 1
    END
END
GO
```

2. Use a cursor to iterate over the identified gaps and execute `fillGap` for each.

```sql
DECLARE @lValue INT, @times INT
 
DECLARE cursorElement CURSOR FOR
SELECT try_cast(replace([PreviousPONumber],'COM','') AS INT) + 1 AS freeValue, Gap - 1 AS times
FROM (
    SELECT *, try_cast(replace([PONumber],'COM','') AS INT) - try_cast(replace([PreviousPONumber],'COM','') AS INT) AS Gap
    FROM (
        SELECT [PONumber], lag([PONumber], 1) OVER (ORDER BY [PONumber]) AS PreviousPONumber
        FROM [amPOrder]) src1
    ) src2
WHERE Gap > 1
 
OPEN cursorElement
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorElement INTO @lValue, @times
WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
BEGIN
    EXEC fillGap @lValue, @times
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorElement INTO @lValue, @times
END
CLOSE cursorElement
DEALLOCATE cursorElement
GO
```

This approach may feel useful to some, especially since identifying the gaps and processing those are clearly distinct.

### SOLVED 2

Thanks to @larnu for comming up with the fastest solution:

```sql
--DELETE FROM fix_amPOrder_PONumber
WITH
    N AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL), (NULL)) AS N(N)),
    Tally AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6),
    ALLCOMs AS (SELECT CONCAT('COM', RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', I), 6)) AS COM FROM Tally),
    COMs AS (
        SELECT COM FROM ALLCOMs
        WHERE COM > (
            SELECT TOP(1) PONumber FROM amPOrder WHERE PONumber IS NOT NULL ORDER BY PONumber ASC
        ) AND COM < (
            SELECT TOP(1) PONumber FROM amPOrder WHERE PONumber IS NOT NULL ORDER BY PONumber DESC
        )
    )
INSERT INTO fix_amPOrder_PONumber
    (lValue)
    SELECT try_cast(replace(C.COM,'COM','') AS INT)
    FROM COMs AS C
    LEFT JOIN amPOrder AS PO ON C.COM = PO.PONumber
    WHERE PO.PONumber IS NULL
    ORDER BY C.COM

GO
```

Thank you all for your fantastic help.

Comment: That is an *awfully* slow method; it will perform incredibly poorly. Why use this when I have given you a tally option, and takes a couple of seconds compared to something that likely takes minutes?

Comment: @Larnu granted it is slow and possibly kludgy. Fact is I am not a DBA but the product owner and need a solution quick. In-house DBAs have not proposed a solution in 4 weeks. Since this should be a 'one shot' operation and not live along the production environment, I have to settle with what I can get.
Your Tally option is very interesting, though it goes beyond my proficiency and I wasn't able to complete it after a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest method to find the missing values would be to use a Tally to generate all the values, then `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6),
COMs AS(
    SELECT CONCAT('COM',RIGHT(CONCAT('000000',I),6)) AS COM
    FROM Tally)
SELECT C.COM
FROM COMs C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON C.COM = YT.PONumber
WHERE YT.PONumber IS NULL;
```

You can easily then manipulate this to `INSERT` the values, or perhaps perform some kind of `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was not able to correctly implement it but it was still insightful to me.

Comment: I am unsure why your query "sometimes" executes fine, but fails most of the time with `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 Invalid column name 'PONumber'. ` even though I correctly updated `dbo.YourTable`

Comment: The query wouldn't "sometimes" do that, @PopGoesTheWza . If you're getting that error it's because the column doesn't exist in the table you are querying.

Comment: I found my mistake... and was able to complete the whole task in a single query. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the SQL LAG() function to access the previous PO Number after ordering the recordset by PO Number. Combine that with some arithmetic to find your gaps...

```
    select *
from 
(
    select
         *
        ,try_cast(replace([PONumber],'COM','') as int) - try_cast(replace([PreviousPONumber],'COM','') as int) as Gap
    from
    (
        select 
             [PONumber]
            ,lag([PONumber],1) over (order by [PONumber]) as PreviousPONumber
        from [amPOrder]
    ) src1
) src2
where Gap > 1
```

This gives you...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with the detailled solution we came up with.